# Why doesn't my octal-to-decimal converter work for certain cases?

Tags: java, binary, octal

I am working on this octal-to-decimal converter:

```
public int getDecimal(String input)
{
    int output = 0;

    // reverse input so that it is easier to work with
    input = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();

    for (int c = 0; c < input.length(); c++)
    {
        // check for invalid digit
        if (input.charAt(c) < '0' || input.charAt(c) > '7')
            return 0;

        if (input.charAt(c) != '0')
        {
            if (input.charAt(c) == '1')
                output += Math.pow(8, c);
            else // if it's greater than 1
                output += Math.pow(8, c) + input.charAt(c) - 1;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

It works for about 65% of the test cases, such as converting "10" to "8." However, it does not work for other cases, such as converting "17" to "15." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your method doesn't appear to take an `input` parameter.

Comment: to get 8^c, use `1 << (c*3)` instead of `pow` which is much slower

Comment: My method now has an `input` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong.

What are you doing at this line,

```
output += Math.pow(8, c) + input.charAt(c) - 1;
```

It should be more like,

```
output += Math.pow(8, c) * (input.charAt(c) - '0');
```

Like, `output += 8^(index) * digit`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember what that "17" means: 1 * 8 + 7.  Your algorithm is wrong.  You don't need to reverse the string.  For each iteration thru the loop, just multiply the previous `output` value by the base (8 in this case) and add the value for the next digit.  Keep going until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
input = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();

System.out.println("input:"+input);

for (int c = 0; c < input.length(); c++) {
    output += Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(c) + "") * Math.pow(8, c);

    System.out.println("output:" + output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (input.charAt(c) != '0')
{
    if (input.charAt(c) == '1')
        output += Math.pow(8, c);
    else // if it's greater than 1
        output += Math.pow(8, c) + input.charAt(c) - 1;
}
```

At least two bugs here. You can reduce all this to

```
output = output*8+input.charAt(c)-'0';
```

after getting rid of the reversing step. Don't worry about the special cases of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too, no need to reverse the string:

```
public static int getDecimal() {
    int output = 0;
    String input="17"; //by example
    int c=input.length();
    int i=0;
    while(c > 0) {
        if (input.charAt(i) < '0' || input.charAt(i) > '7') {
            return 0;
        }
        output += Math.pow(8, c-1) * Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(i++)+"");
        c--;
    }
    return output;
}
```